# How to find number of matches in the array or dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

How to find number of matches in the array or dictionary? for example if the dictionary or the array has the number 4 occurring 5 times, how can I find out about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List elements:

```
my_list = [1,4,7,4,5,7,1,3]
print my_list.count(4)
```

Dictionary values using generator expression:

```
my_dict = {0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 5, 6: 3, 8: 4, 10: 4, 12: 1}
print sum(1 for x in my_dict.values() if x == 4)
```

As pointed out by zondo, the last line can be more simply written as:

```
print sum(x == 4 for x in my_dict.values())
```

due to the fact that `True == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

For a list:

```
my_list = [x for x in [1,4,7,4,5,7,1,3]
len([x for x in my_list if x == 4])
```

For a dictionary (assuming you want to count the values):

```
my_dict = {0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 5, 6: 3, 8: 4, 10: 4, 12: 1}
len([x for x in my_dict.values() if x == 4])
```

The two code segments are counting the number of elements that match the criteria after `if` (in your case, that they equal 4). The `len` function requires a list (not a generator), requiring the extra-looking `[]` in there.